# Image view doesn't display image if screen is not rotated and an other image view has been updated

Tags: java, android

## Issue

I've got an issue with 2 ImageViews on Android.

The first displays a large image. It is inside a RelativeLayout, and is a custom ImageView ([com.ortiz.touch](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)). It was displaying well until now.

The second is also inside the RelativeLayout but is a "normal" ImageView. It shows bluetooth state. Displaying it doesn't cause any issue.

However, when I put code that changes the src of the bluetooth indicator programatically, the first image is not displayed anymore ....

Is the problem coming from the custom view not doing its job right ? Am I missing something ?

## Code

If I'm not doing this kind of stuff :

```
bluetoothState.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_enabled192);
```

The image is displayed correctly.

Here's the layout I use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1b1b1b"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">

    <com.ortiz.touch.TouchImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/emptyDisplayText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#f3f3f3"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth_state"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Desired Result

[image: screenshot]

What I get is the same screen without the central image (the text and bluetooth indication are displayed correctly)

## NB

I'm starting to get quite depressed on that issue. I just want to display 2 images. Thank you.

## Edit

I've not mentioned it, but the main image is loaded in background, using an AsyncTask. I've tried to add some `View.invalidate()` (on top level layout, on image, on bluetooth indication) but it hasn't solved the problem.

In addition to the image appearing on rotation, it also appears when I try to pinch the non-existant image. And trying to reset the zoom (hacky) programatically doesn't work either.

Comment: can you show how you want to display images

Comment: make sure all changes to the ImageViews are done on the UI thread only, including setImageResource

Comment: Tried runOnUIThread, still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found the error.

As I said, I have a AsyncTask (`BitmapWorkerTask`) that I call to load a Bitmap into an ImageView in background.

It's called like this :

```
new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, getApplicationContext()).execute(filename);
```

Changing `getApplicationContext()` to `MainActivity.this` or `getContext()` solves the issue :/ (However, I still find it's quite magic how it worked fine for so long even if application context != activity context !)